# Can the Snow Leopard firewall remember my choices?

Tags: macos, firewall

I have the Snow Leopard firewall switched on. Every now and then, it asks if I'd like to allow or deny network connections for an app. I make a choice, and every time I open the app it asks me again.

Is it possible to save my choices?

Comment: See [“iTunes.app” to accept incoming network connections?](http://superuser.com/questions/42776/itunes-app-to-accept-incoming-network-connections)

Answer (score 3):

See this [support note](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1810) from Apple. About unsigned applications:

> If you run an unsigned application not in the Application Firewall list, you will be presented with a dialog with options to Allow or Deny connections for the application. If you choose Allow, Mac OS X v10.6 will sign the application and automatically add it to the Application Firewall list. If you choose Deny, Mac OS X v10.6 will sign the application, automatically add it to the Application Firewall list and deny the connection.
>
> Some applications check their own integrity when they are run without using code signing. If the Application Firewall recognizes such an application it will not sign it, but then it will re-present the dialog every time the application is run. This may be avoided by upgrading to a version of the application which is signed by its developer.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I am dependent on a signed version being produced... is there any way I can sign an application myself?

Comment: None that I know of (else the signature wouldn't have much security value, I suppose).  But I seem to remember that, when I was asked to allow/deny incoming connections to an application, the same dialog also offered the option to remember that choice in the future.  (Sorry, I wasn't able to force an application to ask me just now so I could be sure).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I would add that self-signed signatures would have value to me - I'd be storing a security decision that I'd made, effectively, which would solve the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

It can (and does) if the app is signed by the developer.

Comment: This has started happening with iTunes which I'd expect to be signed by Apple... any idea why this might be happening?