# How to change the icon (apply a thumb) of a folder on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, icons, finder

In Mac OS X, suppose you open your root disk, following folders/directories will have different icon (thumb) on it.

- Application
- Developer
- Library
- System

How to apply a thumb image on my specific folder/directories?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- locate the image file you want to use
- press Cmd-C (Edit:Copy)
- locate the folder you want the thumbnail applied to
- press Cmd-I (File:Get Info)
- click on the top left icon until it gets a colored outline
- press Cmd-V (Edit:Paste)

You can also copy existing icons, use the Get Info window as source.

Edit:
If this doesn't work, open the image in Preview.app, select part of or the whole image and press Cmd-C (Edit:Copy). Then proceed with step 3.

Comment: Excellent one. ! never mentioned in documents.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with drag'n'drop:

- open info of file(s)/folder(s) to set icon on
- locate your icon (it can be an icon file or just any file, which icon you see for that file will be the one you will set)
- drag icon and drop it on top left icon in info window

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a special Folder-type icon (the usual app bundle .icns won't work here).  Img2icns will give you an option to create this type of icon, despite its name.

Answer (score 1):

[Customizing file and folder icons in Mac OS X](http://davidchambersdesign.com/customizing-file-and-folder-icons-in-mac-os-x/) presents a more involved process utilizing an .icns file which can contain several versions of an icon for display at different sizes. While less elegant than the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>,  <kbd>⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>V</kbd> method, it's useful in cases where scaling a single icon produces unacceptable results (such as when the 16x16 icon is an indistinct blur).

Answer (score 0):

So it cannot be like thumbnail for Pictures folder in Windows? I mean, if I've set the display option to Thumbnails, then if a folder contains images i.e. photos, wallpapers then it gives a preview on the folder icon. I guess it's not there in OS X or any other OS for that matter..

Comment: Mac OS X auto generates thumbnails for PDFs, images and other file types in the Finder in any view.

Comment: Only when you place the folder in the Dock (as a "Stack"), and then it's still rather unusable.