# Change the glyph on a Mac OS X folder icon

Tags: macos, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the icon (apply a thumb) of a folder on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/174240/how-to-change-the-icon-apply-a-thumb-of-a-folder-on-mac-os-x)

I noticed that some system folders on Mac OS X (such as downloads, movies, etc..) have a glyph. Is it possible to add a glyph to some of my own folders?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the icon (apply a thumb) of a folder on Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/174240/how-to-change-the-icon-apply-a-thumb-of-a-folder-on-mac-os-x) and [How can I change an application icon in Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/37811/how-can-i-change-an-application-icon-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate. The possible duplicates refer to replacing an icon entirely; this question refers to *adding a glyph* (e.g., the Applications folder has a stylized A, the Documents folder has a document outline, etc.). Fortunately the question was answered before the heavy-handed moderation nuked it...

Comment: [Telling Folders](http://www.omz-software.de/stuff/) (formerly free, now 1USD via the app store -- still available for download e.g. on softonic) can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a glyph (I'm not going to explain the add an icon part as Chealion & the possible duplicates have already done so) you create an image of a folder with a glyph. :D (using some kind of image editing program). After you are done save it as an icns and use the afore mentioned "change the icon" steps to change your folder's icons.

The stock generic folder icon is found at `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/GenericFolderIcon.icns` or something similar. I'm not sure about the name of the file but the rest of the path is accurate.

You can use Photoshop or something to design your own "glyph" and put it on top of the generic folder, and save it as an icns using one of the multiple free icon creator programs available for download.

To change the system glyphs, modify the appropriate icon files in the folder mentioned above. All the default icons are located in there - this is also where apps like [CandyBar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/) do their work.

Answer (score 3):

I could have swore this is a duplicate...

The system folders have some default icons that can be replaced. You can use programs such as [CandyBar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/) to change these system icons but for changing the icon for any file or folder is relatively simple.

The easiest option is to find the image you want to use as an icon and copy it to your clipboard (use Preview, or it may already have an icon in the Finder). Click on the folder you want to change and choose Get Info from the File Menu (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>).

Click on the icon in the top left so it has a blue outline around it and then press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> or choose Paste from the Edit menu. (To grab the icon from another item just choose Copy from the Edit menu or press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> after clicking on the icon in the Get Info window). Any file or folder can have a custom icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the icons that's used all over. There have even been made apps for it like [candybar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/). But I don't think you can micro manage your icons and use a custom icon for a specific folder.