# Customize the icons of folder on the dock

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, icons, dock

How can I customize the icons of the folders that are in the dock in Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons in the Dock are the same as those used for the folders themselves. Some folders have custom icons by default, based on their name and location, but you cannot do that yourself.

Replace the icon of a file or folder manually as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/174240/how-to-change-the-icon-apply-a-thumb-of-a-folder-on-mac-os-x).

---

Make sure to select *Display as: Folder* in the Dock folder's context-menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Candybar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/) will let you change most any icon in your system. Even the ones in the Dock.