# Home Sharing and Remote on iTunes causing firewall nags

Tags: macos, itunes, iphone, firewall, remote

It seems that enabling Home Sharing and/or hooking up my iPhone's Remote to iTunes causes Mac OS X Snow Leopard's firewall to freak out and keep nagging every time I launch iTunes to ask if I'd like it to accept incoming connections. If I turn off Home Sharing and forget all Remotes, the nag dialog no longer comes up. I could also disable the firewall, but I think that's a silly thing to do.

iTunes is already in the firewall whitelist, so the only thing I know that could cause Mac OS X to nag is a bad application bundle code signature. I checked with this Terminal command:

```
$ codesign -vvv /Applications/iTunes.app/
```

And sure enough, this is what it outputs:

```
/Applications/iTunes.app/: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/AutofillSettings.nib/objects.xib: resource added
/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/iTunesDJSettings.nib/objects.xib: resource added
/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/MobilePhonePrefs.nib/objects.xib: resource added
/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/MobilePhoneSetup.nib/objects.xib: resource added
/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/UniversalAccess.nib/objects.xib: resource added
```

I've tried reinstalling iTunes as suggested by [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/42776/itunes-app-to-accept-incoming-network-connections/42787#42787), but Mac OS X still nags about incoming connections and the exact same output is generated when I run the above command again.

On my PC, Windows Firewall has never nagged whenever I turn on Home Sharing and hook up Remote on my iPhone. <del>Both computers use iTunes 9.2.1.</del> My Mac runs Mac OS X 10.6.4.

Is there anything special I need to do that I might have missed? Or how do I resolve the issue?

**EDIT:** I've updated to iTunes 10, but the nags on my Mac are still there and only go away if I turn off Home Sharing and Remote.

**EDIT 2:** I've updated to Remote 2.0 on my iPhone, but the firewall nags are persisting. Has *anyone* else had this firewall issue at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While updating to iTunes 10.1 and Remote 2.1 *alone* didn't get rid of the nags, I think they did indeed change something, because I just carried out the following and it looks like the nags are gone (for good?):

1. Removed Remote.app from iPhone
2. **iTunes > Preferences > Devices > Forget All Remotes**
3. Quit iTunes
4. **System Preferences > Security > Firewall**, remove iTunes from list of applications
5. Started iTunes
6. Reinstalled Remote.app
7. Coupled iPhone with iTunes
8. Restarted iTunes

I guess the Mac OS X firewall finally figured that iTunes was still iTunes, whether or not I shared my library or linked to any Remotes.

Or my Mac simply wanted to give me a New Year's surprise.

Comment: +1 for following up on your own old question. If only others were this disciplined :-)