# iTunes 10 Network Connection Firewall Problem After .icns Change

Tags: mac, itunes, firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“iTunes.app” to accept incoming network connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/42776/itunes-app-to-accept-incoming-network-connections)

Hi All,

I recently updated to iTunes 10, almost threw up when I saw the new icon on the engadget and gdgt liveblogs and after DLing the latest shiny SW toy immediately replaced the iTunes.icns file in /Applications/iTunes/Resources to something I found and liked.
Since then every time I open iTunes, even if I stay logged in but quit the app, a firewall warning dialog box pops up asking whether I would like to allow or deny network connections.

I've read the previous thread from '09 on this but I was wondering if there was a way to get rid of the Firewall's problem with an altered application. Especially one signed by Apple... Thing is, I want to keep my new .icns but the box is tiring - meaning the "just-download-reinstall-etc" way isn't a solution. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a duplicate as this has a particular reason for the problem

Answer (score 0):

OS X is reading the digital code signature that shipped with iTunes 10. Since you modified the application, the digital signature does not match anymore. OS X will continue to issue the warning that the application was modified unless the signature is changed. You can always try to update the signature by opening up Terminal and typing:

```
cd /Applications
codesign -s iTunes.app/
```

Hopefully, this will alert the system that the signature has changed and make the firewall alert go away.

Comment: Why the down vote? The reason given is correct. The solution does say try and does not comment if it will work but is about the only thing you could try. Perhaps copy the app to somewhere else so Apples updates do not change it.

Comment: nope, no change. problem still there. terminal says (after the codesign command) "no identity found".