# Can I safely delete the files that cause iTunes incoming network connections alerts?

Tags: itunes, osx-lion

I am experiencing the same issue mentioned in ["iTunes.app" to accept incoming network connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/42776/itunes-app-to-accept-incoming-network-connections) but have a question about the files that iTunes creates, which cause this issue.

I have the Firewall turned on in Lion and every time I open iTunes it asks me if I want to allow incoming connections. The solution [seems to be](https://superuser.com/questions/42776/itunes-app-to-accept-incoming-network-connections/189205#189205):

> Go into the iTunes package and delete all of the files that this terminal command flags as a "resource added":
>
> ```
> $ codesign -vvv /Applications/iTunes.app/
> ```
>
> When you rerun the terminal command, it will indicate that iTunes.app now "satisfies its Designated Requirement" and the annoying popup should go away.

However my question is: What are these files iTunes creates and is it safe to delete them? I would like to understand what I am deleting before I just do it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read: [If Mac code signing is tampered with, what might fail?](http://superuser.com/questions/47504/if-mac-code-signing-is-tampered-with-what-might-fail)

Comment: Thanks for the link. So re-signing obviously could break something else. So I either have to disable firewall, live with the constant question or re-install iTunes. The thing I don't get is I just did a clean Lion install and updated iTunes. I have never tampered with it so I don't see why the firewall is doing this.

Comment: It won't really break anything. What I'm wondering: Which files are listed in your case as "resource added"? I also don't see why this would appear out of the blue, but who knows? (I'm not the biggest expert on application security on OS X though)

Comment: i'll run the codesign --verify -vv /Applications/iTunes.app/ tonight and report back what "resources it adds".

Answer (score -1):

This solution didn't work for me, but fortunately I found another way: deleting the whole contents folder and then reinstalling iTunes (in Mountain Lion). I have a longer explanation with pictures posted on my blog if it helps:

http://scientific-ocean.com/mac-quick-tips/

If you adjusted your Mountain Firewall accordingly, i.e., you added iTunes to it, you should not experience this issue. However, for some unknown reason this issue still occurs for many people. A quick solution is simply going to the “Applications” folder, right-click on “iTunes.app”, and click on “Show package contents”. Now, delete the “Contents” folder, which eventually shows up. Next, go to http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/ and download the newest version of iTunes. After the reinstalling it, the problem should be solved.